# Linking libgcc into a -nostdlib compilation

Tags: c, gcc, libgcc

I'm trying to produce a executable without dependency on libc (or any other). First I have done this:

```
// test.c
void _start()
{
    // write(1, "hello!\n", 7);
    asm ("int $0x80"::"a"(4), "b"(1), "c"("hello!\n"), "d"(7));

    // exit(0);
    asm ("int $0x80"::"a"(1), "b"(0));
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -m32 -nostdlib test.c -o test`:

```
hello
```

So far so good. Later I attempted to use some more "advanced" C like `long long`. On 32-bit platforms (my case) this requires `libgcc`:

```
// test.c
void _start()
{
    volatile long long int a = 10;
    volatile long long int b = 5;
    volatile int c = a/b; // Implemented as a call to '__divdi3'
}
```

This fails compilation with `undefined reference to '__divdi3'`. Seems correct as I didn't actually told it to link. But adding the flag `-static-libgcc` does not fix the issue! Why?

Note that I cannot link dynamically to libgcc. The following must hold true:

```
$ ldd test
    not a dynamic executable
```

I'm compiling from 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.8.2 (nothing fancy).

Comment: Using `gcc -v ...` to make sure that you indeed linked to `libgcc` statically.

Comment: Doesn't that interrupt return a result code?  If your asm modifies registers, you must list them as outputs (or clobbers).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd [GCC Inline Assembly](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3): *We shoudn’t list the input and output registers in this list. Because, gcc knows that "asm" uses them (because they are specified explicitly as constraints).*

Comment: While gcc knows the asm uses them, it only knows that they are inputs, not that the asm is going to modify them. As a result, gcc assumes that eax still contains the value 4 on exit, and may re-use that register for another purpose that also requires eax to contain 4.

For example:

`int main()
{
   asm("# %0": : "a" (4));
   return 4;
}`

Compile with -Os -S.  Looking at the .s file, 4 gets loaded into eax before calling the asm (as expected), but NOT after. AAR, if the asm changes eax, the return from main will NOT be 4.  Weirdness ensues.You CANNOT (safely) modify input-only params.

Answer (score 3):

Ended up finding the solution myself. Seems like gcc wasn't able to find the library and didn't bother complaining about it. I ran the following:

```
$ locate libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libgcc.a
```

Then instead of giving `-static-libgcc` to the compiler, I changed the flags to this:

```
gcc -m32 -nostdlib test.c -o test -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32 -lgcc
```

And it compiles and runs just fine!

---

The `-L` is redundant. The following also works:

```
gcc -m32 -nostdlib test.c -o test -lgcc
```

Comment: That `-L` option should not be necessary.

Comment: @LeeDuhem Indeed! It can be replaced by just `-lgcc`